# C# pass string[] array as parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a class that reads all information from file, line by line, into the array `Equipment`. I would like to pass `Equipment` to the `setEquipment` method, and copy them to the `setEquipment` array.

Screenshot with the mistake:
[image: This is a screenshot with the mistake]. What am I'm doing wrong?

```
string[] Equipment, Equipments;
public string[] InitialiseForm()
{
    Equipment = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Temp\\Equipment.txt");
    Equipments = theEntity.setEquipment(Equipment);
    return Equipments;
}
```

This is the method

```
public string[] setEquipment(params string[] newEquipments)
{
    setEquipments = new string[newEquipments.Length];
    newEquipments.CopyTo(setEquipments, 0);

    return setEquipments;
}
```

Comment: In `setEquipment`, you return `Equipments` instead of `setEquipments`

Comment: sorry I've changed it. But it still doesn't work

Comment: `theEntity` is null in your screenshot. Where do you create a `new` instance of `theEntity`?

Comment: Thank you!!! I forget to create instance of theEntity.

Comment: You Should Wrap your code with try catch so that you can trap errors

Comment: OT: either use a `@"..."` (verbatim) string *or* use double (escaped) backslashes - you don't need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, `theEntity` is `null`. Remember to create an instance of the entity before calling its methods.